# Can't boot in kernel 'linux-image-genric 3.0.0.17.20'

Tags: boot, kernel

I have three Linux kernels installed: 12, 16 and 17. Kernel 12 and 16 are working fine. But when I try to boot into `linux-image-generic 3.0.0.17.20`, a red  screen appears and after that, nothing happens.

I think this is caused by an update. Here's a screenshot of the updates I applied today:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit. I'm dual booting with Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay  ! finally I found the problem. The problem does not caused by any updates. The problem was caused by Gparted.

While installing Gparted, never check the ntfsprogs addon. This ugly addon removes a essential program `ntfs-3g` which gives us the write capability to the windows partitions.

> While Installing Gparted I checked "ntfsprogs" and it replaced ntfs-3g. Thats why I could not boot into linux-image-generic  3.0.0.17.30

Now If you have already messed up your system like me, then open synaptic and Install `ntfs-3g`. It will automatically remove `ntfsprogs` and you will be able to boot into image 17 again.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to solve this a few days ago.

When you get to the bootloader (GRUB), and are given the option, pick the one titled "More kernels" or something like that.

Then, once you've done that, pick the one that ends in -12 (or whichever one is lowest) (not recovery).

After that, you should be good to go.

Comment: @CuriousApprentice Now that you have a working system, you should be able to reboot and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but if it was me I would try uninstalling and then re-installing.

First, boot using the `linux-image-3.0.0-16-generic` kernel as you have been and open a terminal (command) window.

Then try to completely uninstall the kernel which will not boot for you using

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.0.0-17-generic
```

I frankly do not know whether removing the kernel headers makes a difference or not. But since I'm somewhat OCD I would also do

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.0.0-17 linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic
```

Assuming the above went well I would then try to re-install using

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.0.0-17-generic  
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.0.0-17 linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic
```

The above is just a guess on my part, but since you say 3.0.0.17 is not working for you anyway it might be worth trying.

Comment: Ok I succeded to remove linux-image-3.0.0-17-generic

Comment: And when you re-installed it? Were you able to boot with it then? (That's the part I was worried about).

Comment: Nope, I could not. But I found the reason of the problem and its solution. Thanks anyway John.

Comment: If possible could you update your question (or answer it) with the solution you found to your problem? Just in case it might be of use to someone else who finds your question via a search.